# How do I delete entries from mappings with user defined types

Tags: solidity, mapping

[user defined value types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html#user-defined-value-types) allow creating a zero cost abstraction over an elementary value type. This is similar to an alias, but with stricter type requirements.

unfortunately, solc 0.8.9 says

> TypeError: Unary operator delete cannot be applied to type MyType

```
type TokenId is uint256;
...
mapping(bytes32 => MyType) public myMapping;
...
delete myMapping[myId];
```

Is there a way to keep `delete` for readability, use the type definition, and avoid multiple additional `wrap` and `unwrap` ?

Comment: can you add the `MyType` struct/type with your question?

Comment: @hack3r_0m I read the question as they were asking the case `MyType = TokenId`, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can not delete an entry of mapping when using User Defined Value Types. The reason here is no initial default value of user-defined types.

As explained in solidity docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html?highlight=User%20Defined%20Value%20Types#user-defined-value-types) and [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html?highlight=delete#delete)

> A user defined value type is defined using `type C is V`, where `C` is
> the name of the newly introduced type and `V` has to be a built-in
> value type (the “underlying type”).
>
> The `type C` does not have any operators or bound member functions. In
> particular, even the operator `==` is not defined. Explicit and
> implicit conversions to and from other types are disallowed.

> What `delete a` does is it assigns the initial value for the type to
> `a`.  It is important to note that `delete a` really behaves like an
> assignment to `a`, i.e. it stores a new object in `a`.

I think since user-defined types have no operators or bound members functions assigning an initial of user defined (inherited from the underlying type) type is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't delete a mapping entry. You can write over it or set it back to false but you can't delete.

Comment: The line `delete myMapping[myId]` does work when myMapping is declared as `mapping(bytes32 => uint256)`.

Comment: You might be mistaking with Struct and mapping that point to struct

Comment: Declaring `mapping(bytes32 => uint256) public myMapping;` and then executing in a function `bytes32 myId = 0x1234...; delete myMapping[myId];` works in solidity v0.8.9.

Comment: `delete myMapping[myId]` is possible whereas `delete myMapping` is not valid. Because can't set all the mapping key-value pairs to their initial value as keys are arbitrary and unknown. Whereas it is possible to `delete a` where a can be dynamic array or static array, it will set all elementals to their initial value.

Comment: So why is this question still open??

Comment: I think If questions is how to delete `mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType)` where _keyType is built-in types and _ValueType is user-defined type it is not possible. If both key and value are build-in types it is possible to delete entries by passing the key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an appropriated way but that's how i create and destroy a new mapping :

```
contract Mapping {

    mapping (uint256 => uint256) public map;
    // workaround because i can't find a way to directly access to the map on contract MyContract
    function write(uint256 index, uint256 data) public {
        map[index] = data;
    }
}

contract MyContract {
    
    Mapping big_array = new Mapping();
    
    function write(uint256 index, uint256 data) public {
        big_array.write(index,data);
    }
    
    function read(uint256 index) public returns (uint256) {
        return big_array.map(index); // it works, i would like something like that instead of Mapping.write
    }
    
    function newMap() public {
        delete big_array;
        big_array = new Mapping();    
    }
    
}
```

but ofc it's only useful if you want to delete the whole entries not one in particular.

Comment: The question is about deleting an entry of the mapping.